# Cannot start tomcat server when having "spring-boot-starter-test" dependency in classpath

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-starter

My spring boot web application stopped immediately without any error message when starting:

```
:: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.1.RELEASE)

2018-04-19 17:15:34.009  INFO 5600 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-04-19 17:15:34.013  INFO 5600 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.29
2018-04-19 17:15:34.027  INFO 5600 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/whf/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
2018-04-19 17:15:34.129  INFO 5600 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-04-19 17:15:34.514  INFO 5600 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
```

When I removed the `spring-boot-starter-test` dependency the problem went away. Here is my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hyperledger.fabric-sdk-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>fabric-sdk-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0-alpha</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- remove this dependency can fix this problem -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I have no idea what's going on here....

-----update------

Changing spring boot version to `1.5.x` solved the problem. Is it a bug of spring boot 2.0.1?

---------update-------

It seems that something stops the logs from printing to console.

Comment: I am running into exactly the same issue.  I narrowed it down a tiny bit further.  It seems to be related to the spring-core dependency within spring-boot-starter-test.  If I use the following it also gets me past the issue:
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>

Comment: @beldenge Tried your solution, works! You should post this as an answer here.

Comment: @beldenge Any idea about the exact cause of this issue?

Comment: No I am not sure what the exact issue is but I believe it is a bug in Spring Boot with how the dependencies are structured and/or scoped in the spring-boot-starter-test pom.  If I get around to it, I plan to file a Jira for it.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13047

Comment: @beldenge Got it. I'm the one who providing the sample project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, I'm posting this as an answer, even though I consider it more of a workaround.  I was running into exactly the same issue and was able to narrow it down a tiny bit further. It seems to be related to the spring-core dependency within spring-boot-starter-test. If I use the following it also works:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar issue. In my case I excluded common-logging from run-time. I added below configuration in build.gradle file.

```
configurations {
    runtime.exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'       
}
```